# Why is comment history a mod-only privilege?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderator-tools, comment-edits

I just noticed recently that edited comments get this cute little pencil next to them. What I also noticed is that as a mod I can see the entire edit history of the comment, but non-mods cannot.

Regular users can see edit history on regular posts, so why not comments? The fact that mods can edit any comment at any time *and* that there is no way for the community to see the exact change is a bit concerning, and also doesn't seem to fit with the philosophy guiding other content on the SE sites.

What is the reasoning why comment history is a mod-only privilege?

Comment: It's extremely rare that a moderator ever *should* edit a comment versus just deleting it. A comment's history should only ever consist of edits by the author of the comment during their grace period.

Comment: @animuson Why does it exist if you're never to use it? I might suggest that honest mods *knowing* there is no transparency in comment edits will intentionally avoid them. If there was transparency, editing becomes less of an issue. Or take away the mod edit power. It's inconsistent with the philosophy guiding posts.

Comment: @frеdsbend Because in those rare cases it can be useful. Comments very generally are not treated consistently with posts. Comments are deleted freely, posts deleted cautiously. Posts are ideally managed by voting through the community, comments are primarily managed by moderators. Mods are trusted more than other users, and are still subject to oversight by CMs etc.

Comment: @BryanKrause and what are those rare cases in which it is useful? As a mod, I have no intention of ever editing another user's comment, precisely because of the lack of transparency of that action.

Comment: @wimi - It's as transparent as any other moderator only action.

Comment: One thing I've learned is that they edit out "+1"s and "-1"s.

Comment: @BryanKrause I understand. I delete a lot of comments ... What I don't understand is why I can edit them *and* no one can see the edit history.

Comment: @wimi One example is a user who would like to edit their comment but is too late to do so. It's also an alternative to comment deletion, but yes that is quite rare. Some mods may do it more often to preserve useful content while removing that which infringes, though like you I rarely edit (maybe never have? I can't actually recall a case).

Comment: *"In all other situations, comments cannot be edited. However, in lieu of editing, they may be deleted and resubmitted."*. Official FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/803868 I would not edit a user's comment because they asked.

Comment: @frеdsbend But if the comment on a long thread already gained tons of votes, deleting wouldn't be so desirable.

Comment: I've only ever edited for pedantry. Misspellings, grammar, etc. I did it about 10 times when I first became a mod. Then I decided that was a waste of my time. There was also the concern that I unintentionally change the meaning.

Comment: @wimi Another example I can think of is to fix a broken link (this one I think I've actually done...). If the user's intent is clear, I don't see a problem with editing to make their comment functional; it's a lot quicker than pinging them to suggest a fix, and cleaner than adding an additional comment correcting it.

Comment: The only time I ever edit a user's comment is to remove the @-mention from it, due to a user deletion or renaming, and the comment is still somewhat useful. I prefer simply deleting comments in all other cases.

Comment: Sometimes a comment has a useful part worth keeping, and a part that should be deleted because irrelevancy or similar.   **I like cheese** (for example)

Comment: There are a handful of good comments with the addition of unnecessary expletive. Also, some "Not an answer" answers were particularly worthy to be converted to comment, but some of the wordings/formattings might not make sense as a comment (e.g. code fence vs inlined code block)

Comment: I just converted an answer to a comment and *needed* to edit it so that it made sense in the context of a comment, rather than an answer. The alternative was to just delete the answer. I really wish the comment edit action were more publicly visible.

Answer (score 16):

<sub>**I'm not answering the "why", but skipping directly to a possible solution**</sub>

I think the sensible way to deal with this is:

- Let mods see all history to check any violations, flags, complaints (as it is)
- Let **any user see the history for his own comments only**:

  So they can check and audit for any mod interference, but still have some privacy fixing comments in the grace time (also keeping private any mod/user fix for general public).

  This was asked here: [Please make the revision histories of comments visible to their authors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381465/)

PS: Just some context on why a mod sometimes need to edit a comment from another user:

- Fixing links in useful comments
- Fixing code (and general) formatting when converting "non answers" that can serve as useful comments
- In exceptional cases, removing some CoC/Legal violation that is not too serious when most of the comment is very useful or relevant (rare/edge cases, but possible).

Not limited to this, of course.

Comment: Related FR: [Please make the revision histories of comments visible to their authors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381465/)